# VirtualDub can't record audio, no inputs/sources showing up

Tags: audio, video, record, capture, virtualdub

I'm using VirtualDub version 1.9.11 to screen capture video game play on my computer.  It works amazing for video; however, I can't get my audio to record.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte ga-z77x-ud5h.  And I have downloaded the latest audio drivers and even tried older drivers.

[image]
Here is an image of what my Sound options in VirtualDub SHOULD resemble.  This comes from this VirtualDub tutorial http://www.genadmission.com/vdubguide.html

[image]
Here is what my inputs look like, none...

[image]
And here are what my sources look like, none...

Any clues on why I have no sources and no inputs?  If I plug in a microphone I can get mic input, but that's it.

I learned about uisng VirtualDub from this video tutorial  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvfPXn5VQ0w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  Had to enable Stereo mix which was disabled by defualt... why on earth would Windows 7 disable that by default is beyond me.

Seen on this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjQ_qS-LaoU

Comment: How do you screen capture with Virtual Dub ? I have it downloaded but can't figure out.

Comment: where can i find Stereo mix on Windows Vista ?

Answer (score 0):

I've run DIMH and SFC to see if there are any errors on the system. SFC said a couple of directories had dual owners and corrected that, but it didn't help.

I tried re-connecting the Pinnacle device, thinking that giving the system a choice of more than one device might fix something. VirtualDub sees both video capture devices and will use either one: but it still does not give me a choice of audio input devices.

However, it will let me take the video from the FHD HDMI input and sound from the Pinnacle device, so I have a work-around. It's stupid, and I'd really like to get this working properly, but at least I can use this solution.